# Max-weight path of fixed length?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I have a problem which I've reduced down to the following requirements:

Given an:

- undirected graph $G$ that may contain cycles, with positive weighted nodes and edges of length $1$,
- a subset of nodes $M$,
- a length $L$,

return the path of maximum weight (calculated by summing up the weights of its nodes) that contains all nodes in $M$ and is exactly length $L$.

(A more complex requirement that I'm omitting is that including certain nodes in the path may increase the values of other nodes.)

I'm just looking for a nod in the right direction - are there any algorithms or terms that might be relevant to this situation?

Comment: If $L+1$ happens to be the number of nodes in the graph and the path is required to be simple, this becomes the Hamiltonian path problem...

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like "Weight Constrained Shortest Path" or "Restricted Shortest Path"

Comment: Googling these terms returns a number of links. Even though links can go stale, some references or links would add to this answer.